# Powershell LinkClicked event for a RichTextBox

Tags: powershell, richtextbox, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

Im using windows Windows.Forms.RichTextBox to redirect my powershell script output "$var".
Detect.Urls is already enabled and working, but unable to open them by clicking.

Can any one help me with the code for link click event handler in powershell script........

```
$outputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox 
$outputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,150) 
$outputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(700,300) 
$outputBox.MultiLine = $True
$outputBox.SelectionIndent = 8
$outputBox.SelectionHangingIndent = 3
$outputBox.SelectionRightIndent = 12
$outputBox.ScrollBars = "ForcedBoth"
$Form.Controls.Add($outputBox)
$outputBox.Text = $var
$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
[void] $Form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle click events by yourself

```
$outputBox.add_LinkClicked({
    Start-Process -FilePath $_.LinkText
})
```

Will open link in the default browser when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it with Powershell Studio...right click the control and add a new event...add the linkclicked event and then go to the script and add the following.
depending on what you want to be opened you may need to used something other than explorer, but the $_.linktext should have the link you want from the url.  note if there are spaces you will have to something to replace them as the url will be broke at the first space it encounters.

```
$Linkclicked = $_.LinkText
explorer.exe $Linkclicked
```